# Comment « à » et « près » se sont-ils combinés pour signifier « excepté » ?

Tags: étymologie

[Cet article sur Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition) m'a introduit à la Locution Prépositive [à … près](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_%E2%80%A6_pr%C3%A8s) (cf. aussi [le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/pr%C3%A8s])):

> 1. Excepté.
> 2. Avec une différence de. Il s’en faut de.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Près** signifie la proximité,

> Être *près de* quelqu'un, être tout près de quelqu'un (avec *tout* il y a encore moins de distance, mais cette dernière existe).

**À** marque ici un rapport de position.

> Vous êtes *à* gauche.

*À peu près* signifie *presque près*, donc vous n'êtes pas exactement à l'endroit dont on parle.

***À*** un détail **près**, c'est-à-dire que si l'on enlève *ce détail* qui est *près de* ce qui est exprimé, on est *exactement* là où l'on veut être : *excepté* ce détail, tout est correct, exact, comme on le souhaite.